# curved lines with EaselJS

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I have a drawing canvas using EaselJS, the problem is that when I am drawing lines is working properly only the first one. Since second line is getting with some corners not with curved line as the first line, and it looks more like a polygon than a curved line. What is the best way to fix this?

I think here should to be something to correct

```
      //containers
        this.backgroundContainer = new createjs.Container();
        this.stage.addChild(this.backgroundContainer);

        var ss = new createjs.Shape();
        ss.graphics.beginFill("#000000").drawRect(0, 0, 960, window.innerHeight);

        this.stageArea = new createjs.Container();
        this.stageArea.snapToPixel = true;
        this.stageArea.hitArea = ss;
        this.backgroundContainer.addChild(this.stageArea);    


        this.container = new createjs.Container();          
        this.stage.addChild(this.container);    


        this.stageArea.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleMouseDown);
        this.stage.addEventListener("stagemousemove" , this.handleMouseMove);   



            tick:function(){

            if(app.mouseDOWN){

            app.midPt = new createjs.Point(app.oldPt.x + app.stage.mouseX - app.stage.canvas.width/2>>1, app.oldPt.y+app.stage.mouseY - app.stage.canvas.height/2>>1);


           app.lineArray[app.NUM_LINES].graphics
           .beginStroke('#ffffff')
           .moveTo(app.midPt.x, app.midPt.y)
           .curveTo(app.oldPt.x, app.oldPt.y, app.oldMidPt.x, app.oldMidPt.y);

            app.lineArray2[app.NUM_LINES].graphics
           .beginStroke('#ffffff')
           .moveTo(app.midPt.x, app.midPt.y)
           .curveTo(app.oldPt.x, app.oldPt.y, app.oldMidPt.x, app.oldMidPt.y);

            app.lineArray3[app.NUM_LINES].graphics
           .beginStroke('#ffffff')
           .moveTo(app.midPt.x, app.midPt.y)
           .curveTo(app.oldPt.x, app.oldPt.y, app.oldMidPt.x, app.oldMidPt.y);

            app.oldPt.x = app.stage.mouseX;
            app.oldPt.y = app.stage.mouseY;

            app.oldMidPt.x = app.midPt.x;
            app.oldMidPt.y = app.midPt.y;


            app.stage.update();
        }   



    }
```

Comment: We need to see the code you have problems with.

Comment: well it is a big code and I really don't know what to give you first. If is helping I can post a demo page to see how it is working

Comment: Only the relevant part (for example where you try to draw the actual curve)

Comment: have a look on my edit

Comment: I have changed the code because I realised that here is actually drawing